# C++ store and retrieve UTC time with DST info to/from database

Tags: c++, mysql, oracle, sqlite, datetime

I´m using C++ under Linux and I confess that after reading so many posts on the theme I´m litte confused around `time_t`, `struct` `tm`, `time`, `ctime` and `strftime`.

What I need to do is to get the current system date/time, convert it to UTC and store in database. Later on I need to retrieve that date/time and print on screen in a human readable format.

I´m using Oracle (`TIMESTAMP`), mySQL (`DATETIME`) and Sqlite3 (has no datetime field, stored either on a `INT` or a `VARCHAR()`).

The most important is that I need to store date/time with current time zone considering the DST time, as when I get back the result I can recover the original time zone of the DST for correct information display.

Something like:

```
// Get current time 
std::time_t now = std::time(0); 

// Convert it to Oracle ???
? oracletime = ?;

// Convert it to mySQl ???
? mysqltime = ?;

// store it on Sqlite3
int sqlite3time = now;

// print the time
std::cout << now << std::endl;
```

What would be the correct conversion steps here ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you store an [ISO](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) string representation of the time? That way you can keep the timezone information.

Comment: How to convert from C++ to ISO and the way back...